# How to customize the windows shell to display files from a remote source and allow custom drawing?

Tags: windows, winapi, shell, customization, windows-explorer

Is it possible, (via some shell extension or similar) to customize the Windows shell (explorer.exe) to accomplish the following?

Make it, upon navigating to a predefined path:

1. draw over its surface - custom background, or even add custom forms for data input
2. display custom listview items based on the "virtual" path provided (something analogous to what explorer is doing when browsing a FTP repository - the items shown are not contents of a local folder, but rather some "virtual" items physically located on the FTP server)

The idea is to reuse the visage and navigation elements of Explorer without re-implementing the whole functionality and make it look native on all Windows versions for a remote file browser (file lists+files alone served by a custom web service).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to implement a [Explorer Namespace Extension](http://www.microsoft.com/msj/archive/S332.aspx). There is some good information floating around on [codeproject](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/shell/namespcextguide1.aspx) etc that you will probably need since the [official documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc144093(v=VS.85).aspx) is not the best.